# LocalForage return mismatched value type

Tags: typescript, ionic3, localforage

I'm trying to use `LocalForage` library on my `Ionic3` `typescript` app.

`LocalForage` is used into a `injectable` service like this

```
import {Injectable} from '@angular/core';
import localForage from "localforage"

@Injectable()
export class LocalStorageService {

  constructor(private localForage: LocalForage) {
  }


  getAccessToken() {
    return this.localForage.getItem('accessToken').then((token) => token);
  };

  setAccessToken(token: String){
    this.localForage.setItem('accessToken', token);
  }
}
```

And then on my component class I have something like this

```
...
token:string;
...

this.localStorageService.getAccessToken().then(token=> {
this.token = token;
})
```

And it returns this error:

```
TS2345:Argument of type '{}' is not assignable to parameter of type 'string'
```

What I'm doing wrong?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

To me it looks like there's no need for `getAccessToken`s last item in promise chain, so you can try something like this:

```
  getAccessToken() {
    return this.localForage.getItem('accessToken');
  };
```

Comment: yes, you are right but the problem persist. If I cast result of the promise like this `this.token = token as string;` works fine but I don't know what returns localforage with a getItem

Comment: What about declaring the token type as lowercase 'string': `setAccessToken(token: string)`?

Comment: Same result, If I remove de `as string` it returns the error